# add custom fa-icons add on JsTree

Tags: javascript, ajax, jstree

```js
 $(function () {
    // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
    $('#jstree').jstree();
    // 7 bind to events triggered on the tree
    $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
      //console.log(data.selected);
    });
    // 8 interact with the tree - either way is OK
    $('button').on('click', function () {
      $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
      $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
      $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jsTree test</title>
  <!-- 2 load the theme CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.jstree.com/3.3.8/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- 3 setup a container element -->
  <div id="jstree">
    <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
    <ul>
      <li>Root node 1
        <ul>
          <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
          <li>Child node 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  

  <!-- 4 include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- 5 include the minified jstree source -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Current output is:-

[image]

Expected output is:-

[image]

i wanted to do this type of tree 
thanks advance..

Comment: jstree provided data-jstree='{"icon":"//jstree.com/tree.png"}' icons but i wanted to use fa-icons.

Comment: include class manually to li like <li class="fa fa-address-book">Child node 2</li>

Comment: i try to add manually seems it's not working. @rajesh

Comment: Please use ref link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644534/customise-icons-on-js-tree/35645646] it will help you to solve your issue

Comment: yeah thanks men. @rajesh